# Regex allow 1 leading zero only before floating decimal

Tags: regex

Currently I have the following regex:

```
/^[0-9]{0,13}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/
```

it allows:

- 0 to 13 digits between 0 and 9 before a decimal
- 0 to 2 digits after decimal place

passing currently:

```
1000900.87
65677987897
908181.0
.89
9879
0.89
0.9
```

However, I would like it to only allow 1 leading 0.

Currently, these pass and I would like them to fail:

```
00000001.89
000.76
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex matches a single dot but is also matches an empty line as all the parts are optional due to `{0,13}` and `)?`

If you don't want to match an empty string, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching either 1-13 digits followed by an optional part that matches a dot and 1-2 digits or `|` match only a dot followed by 1-2 digits.

To make sure the digits do not start with 2 or more zeroes you could use a negative lookahead to assert that that is not the case.

```
^(?:(?!0{2,})\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fe7AOZ/1)

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `(?!0{2,})` Negative lookahead to make sure what follows are not 2 or more zeroes
- `\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match 1-13 digits with an optional part that matches a dot and 1-2 digits
- `|` Or
- `\.\d{1,2})` Match a dot and 1-2 digits
- `$` End of the string

Edit: As pointed out by @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, if it is also valid to match a dot at the end you could add the third alternation `|\d+\.` matching 1+ digits follwed by a dot:

```
^(?!0{2,})(?:\d{1,13}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2}|\d+\.)$
```

See the updated [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5dSOZh/1/)

Comment: This doesn't match `10.` which is a valid number and even OP's own regex allows matching `10.`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thank you for your comment. That variation is not listed in the example data but have updated my answer taking that variation into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a negative look `(?!0{2,})` ahead to reject the match which contains more than two leading zeroes in your input. Use this regex,

```
^(?!0{2,})[0-9]{0,13}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^ This negative look ahead will reject the match if it sees more than two leading zeroes
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UyGvR7/3)**

However, you regex also allows a single dot `.` as valid which I don't think you should allow and for rejecting that as well, just add another negative look ahead 
`(?!\.$)` and your regex becomes better,

```
^(?!0{2,})(?!\.$)[0-9]{0,13}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

**[Demo not allowing just a single dot](https://regex101.com/r/UyGvR7/4)**

Comment: For the second modification, is there any reason to choose adding additional negative look ahead instead of just changing the last quantifiers to `{1,2}`? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: @EralpŞahin: If you make last quantifier as `{1,2}` then you will not be able to support numbers like `10.` which are perfectly valid numbers in most languages.

Comment: It appears your solution allows for a letter in the chain of characters.
0898i9
08i98
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ckIQfX/1)

Comment: @JakeMetz: Aah, I just extended your regex and missed to see even you too forgot to escape `.` in your post. That unscaped `.` will allow any character hence needed to escape that as well.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You are right, didn't think of that.